# XML only stores 79 entries? - PHP webscraper

Tags: php, xml

I have been playing around with a simple php webscraper I've built for a small project of mine. The scraper is running through jobposts on a website and storing all relevant information in an nested array, which I then store in an xml-file. However, the problem is that whenever i run the code it only store the first 79 jobposts and i can't seem to find the problem (I know there are more jobposts with the class I'm searching for).

If anyone can point me in the right direction or have tried something similar themselves, it whould be nice to get a solution :)

I'm running the server locally via. MAMP. Don't know if that could be the problem?

```
  include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $Pages = array();
    $JobOffers = array();

$html = file_get_html("https://www.jobindex.dk/jobsoegning?q=studiejob");   
$NumPage = $html->find('li.page-item');

foreach ($NumPage as $page){
    
    $res = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $page->plaintext);
    $PageNumber = $res.trim(); 
    $PageNumToInt = (int)$PageNumber;
    array_push($Pages, $PageNumToInt);
    }
    
$HighestValue = max($Pages);


for($i = 8; $i <= $HighestValue; $i++){
    
    $Newhtml = file_get_html("https://www.jobindex.dk/jobsoegning?page=".$i."&q=studiejob");
    $items = $Newhtml->find('div.PaidJob');
    

    
    foreach ($items as $job){
        
        $RareTitle = $job->find("a", 0)->plaintext;
        $CommonTitle = $job->find("a", 1)->plaintext; 
        $Virksomhed = $job->find("a", 2)->plaintext;
        $LinkHref = $job->find("a", 1)->href;
        $DisP1 = $job->find("p", 1)->plaintext; 
        $DisP2 = $job->find("p", 2)->plaintext; 
        $Dis = $DisP1 . " " . $DisP2;
        $date = date("d/m/Y");
        $prefix = "JoIn";
        
        echo $RareTitle; 
        echo $CommonTitle; 
        echo $Virksomhed; 
        echo $LinkHref; 
        echo $Dis; 
        echo $date; 
        echo $prefix; 
    
        $SingleJob = array($CommonTitle, $RareTitle, $Virksomhed, $Dis, $LinkHref, $date, $prefix);
        array_push($JobOffers,$SingleJob);

}}
```

This code is for saving the job offers in local xml file:

```
function SaveJobs($JobInfo){

if(file_exists("./xml/JobOffers.xml")){
 $i = 1; 
    foreach ($JobInfo as $jobs){
            $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8"); 
            $xml->load("./xml/JobOffers.xml");
            
            // Creating textnode with line break 
            $textNode = $xml->createTextNode("\n"); 
            
            // root Element
            $root = $xml->getElementsByTagName("job")->item(0);
            $root->appendChild($textNode);
            
            // Create Singlejob Element
            $SingleJob = $xml->createElement("Jobitem");
            
            //ID Attribute 
            $DomAtt1 = $xml->createAttribute('ID'); 
            $DomAtt1->value = $i.$jobs[6];
            $SingleJob->appendChild($DomAtt1); 
            
            //Date Attribute
            $DomAtt2 = $xml->createAttribute('Date'); 
            $DomAtt2->value = $jobs[5];
            $SingleJob->appendChild($DomAtt2); 
            
            
            // Creating Elements 
            $TitleElement = $xml->createElement("Title", $jobs[0]);
            $SecTitle = $xml->createElement("SecTitle", $jobs[1]); 
            $Firm = $xml->createElement("Firm", $jobs[2]); 
            $dis = $xml->createElement("Description", $jobs[3]); 
            $Linkhref = $xml->createElement("Linkhref", $jobs[4]); 
            
             
                    
            // Append data to SingleJob Element
            $SingleJob->appendChild($TitleElement);
            $SingleJob->appendChild($SecTitle);
            $SingleJob->appendChild($Firm);
            $SingleJob->appendChild($dis);
            $SingleJob->appendChild($Linkhref);
            
            
            // Append Singlejob to root and save the changes
            $root->appendChild($SingleJob);
            $xml->save("./xml/JobOffers.xml");
    
            $i++; 
        } 
        
    
}}
```

Comment: Possibly the page itself you are scraping has "pagination". Looks like you address that in your code though. Then possibly your requests are coming too fast to their server, and thus, subsequent requests are being rejected: Consider putting in an artificial delay between requests.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip! I will try :)